# Learning pipes, exec, fork, and trying to chain three processes together

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork, pipe

I'm learning to use pipes and following along with this code on [pipes](http://www.man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/pipes/pipe_ls_wc.c.html).  The program makes two child processes using fork.  The first child runs 'ls' command and outputs to pipe1.  The second reads from pipe1 runs 'wc' and outputs to stdout.

I'm just trying to add a third process in the middle that reads from pipe1 and outputs to pipe2. Basically what I'm trying to do

```
  ls | cat | wc -l
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
(ls)stdout -> pipe1 -> stdin(cat)stdout-> stdin(wc -l) -> stdout
```

Nothing ever prints to stdout and the program never exits.

Here's my code with the changes for process #3

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int pfd[2];                                     /* Pipe file descriptors */
    int pfd2[2];

    if (pipe(pfd) == -1)                            /* Create pipe */
        perror("pipe");

    if (pipe(pfd2) == -1)                            /* Create pipe */
        perror("pipe");

    /*
    Fork process 1 and exec ls command
    write to pfd[1], close pfd[0]
    */
    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");

    case 0:             
        if (close(pfd[0]) == -1)                   
            perror("close 1");

        // dup stdout on pfd[1]
        if (pfd[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {            
            if (dup2(pfd[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 2");
            if (close(pfd[1]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
        }
        execlp("ls", "ls", (char *) NULL);          
        perror("execlp ls");
    default:            
        break;
    }

    /*
    *   Fork process 2 and exec wc command
    read from pfd[0], close pfd[1]
    write to pfd[1], close pfd2[0]
    */
    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
    case 0:  
        // read from pfd[0]           
        if (close(pfd[1]) == -1)                  
            perror("close 3");

        if (pfd[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {            
            if (dup2(pfd[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 2");
            if (close(pfd[0]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
        }

        if (pfd2[1] != STDOUT_FILENO) {            
            if (dup2(pfd2[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 2");
            if (close(pfd2[1]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
        }

        execlp("cat", "cat", (char *) NULL);
        perror("execlp cat");
    default:
        break;
    }

    /*
    *   Fork process 3
    */
    switch (fork()) {
    case -1:
        perror("fork");
    case 0:          
        if (close(pfd2[1]) == -1)                  
            perror("close 3");

        if (pfd2[0] != STDIN_FILENO) {            
            if (dup2(pfd2[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1)
                perror("dup2 2");
            if (close(pfd2[0]) == -1)
                perror("close 4");
        }

        execlp("wc", "wc", "-l", (char *) NULL);
        perror("execlp wc");
    default:
        break;
    }


    /* Parent closes unused file descriptors for pipe, and waits for children */

    if (close(pfd[0]) == -1)
        perror("close 5");
    if (close(pfd[1]) == -1)
        perror("close 6");
    if (close(pfd2[0]) == -1)
        perror("close 5");
    if (close(pfd2[1]) == -1)
        perror("close 6");

    if (wait(NULL) == -1)
        perror("wait 1");
    if (wait(NULL) == -1)
        perror("wait 2");
    if (wait(NULL) == -1)
        perror("wait 3");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: Note that `perror()` simply prints an error message; it does not exit.  You have case statements that will report errors and then fall through to the next case, which is _not_ what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you did not close `pfd[1]` in process 3, add `close(pfd[1]);` after case 0 in that process 3 will fix it.

In process 3, that `cat` will read from `pfd[0]`, however there are four `pfd[1]` in those processes:

1. process 0

   this is the main process, `pfd[1]` in this process will be closed by that close before `wait()`.
2. process 1

   after `ls` finished, `pfd[1]` in this process will be closed automatically by the operating system.
3. process 2

   `pfd[1]` has been closed before executing `cat`.
4. process 3

   `pfd[1]` is open in this process while `wc` is running, and this is what happened at that moment:

   1. in process 2, `cat` tries to read `pfd[0]` for data from `pfd[1]`
   2. in process 3, `wc` tries to read `pfd2[0]` for data from `pfd2[1]`
   3. because `pdf[1]` still open in process 3, and nothing will be written to it, reading from `pfd[0]` in process 2 (cat) will wait forever
   4. because `cat` in process 3 still alive, reading from `pfd2[0]` in process 3 (wc) will wait (forever)

As you can see, you have a deadlock between process 2 (cat) and process 3 (wc) because of file descriptor leak. To break this deadlock, you just need to close `pfd[1]` in process 3 before you run `wc`, after that:

1. `cat` in process 2 will exit after `ls` in process 1 exits, because there is nothing left for it (cat) to read
2. after `cat` in process 2 exits, `wc` in process 3 will also exit, because there is nothing left for it (wc) to read
3. after that, the main process (parent process) will exit, and the program will finish.

---

It is possible that there are more than one write ends for the read end of a pipe, unless all these write ends are closed, end-of-file will not be delivered to the read end, and the reader will just wait for more data to come. If there is nothing to come, that reader will wait forever.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks.  I'm still unsure of why it worked though.  I think I need to read up a bit more on how pipes work.  Process 3 doesn't use pfd for either its' stdin or stdout so I didn't think I would need to close it.

Comment: @JDD It is possible that there are more than one write ends for the read end of a pipe, unless all these write ends are closed, end-of-file will not be delivered to the read end, and the reader will just wait for more data to come. If there is nothing to come, this is your case, that reader will wait forever.

Comment: I see.  I didn't know they worked like that.  Thanks!

Comment: +1, but I think a cleaner solution is to close the pipe in the default case (the parent) after the fork of the process that uses the pipe.  In general, create your pipes as close to the fork as possible, and close them as soon as possible.